# check if dynamic element exists in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Data is being sent to my webpage and I collect it using these lines of code:

```
        var bytes = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
        Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(content);
```

Afterwards I try to collect the param which is sometimes empty and other times contains an int so I have made this code to check if it is an int or not:

```
        int metaDataExpMonth = 0;
        bool isSuccessExpMonth = int.TryParse(item["metadata"] 
        ["exp_month"].ToString(), out metaDataExpMonth);
```

But for some reason it will not parse the item when it is not empty - and it contains a digit such as 9 but throws an exception instead.

I cannot debug the code locally so I have no idea how to fix the bug.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a real, working example.  However, it is possible that the input contains non-printable characters (ascii  0-31), which could make it look like the 9 was first when viewing the output.

Comment: It is only when I add the - ToString() that it throws an error (if item contains a digit value) - but then if the ToString() is not there it will throw an error when the item is null.

Comment: @NickDeveloper - This is why a [mcve] is so valuable. If you could show us the input which leads to these errors then we could solve in 30 seconds.